# If then else within a select

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I am trying to make a script faster and I have decided to include some calculations that used to happen in PHP inside SQL. I have to make an if statement which decides whether to use `insert` or `update` if it's needed with the code:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `edenteva` WHERE `Time`='1340252716' and `Code`='571119'))
THEN IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `map` WHERE `mega`='571119'))
THEN UPDATE `map` SET `edenteva`='571119' WHERE `mega`='571119'
ELSE INSERT INTO `map`(`mega`,`edenteva`) VALUES ('571119','571119');
```

But, I am getting a syntax error, can you see what is wrong?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `edenteva` WHERE `Time`='1340252716'
>   and `Code`='57111' at line 1

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need those brackets around exists.

Comment: not a MySQL expert here, but I'm guessing you just forgot to `END` your `IF`s.

Comment: Might be a cleaner option for you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html (it depends on the unique indexes you have - this can be very efficient.)

Comment: Thanx Andrew, best answer yet, i didnt know that.

Comment: I think it is not possible to use the duplicate key statement in your case since your conditions are various, and not all on the table you are actually inserting to.

Comment: @Sebas: I think it is possible.

Comment: @Andrew, why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `map.mega` has a `UNIQUE` index defined on it (or it's a `PRIMARY KEY`) we can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` thus:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE map (mega, edenteva)
VALUES ('571119','571119')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE edenteva = '571119';
```

If we only want to do the update or insert when there's a row in another table, we can use the other table as the source for the values:

```
INSERT INTO map (mega, edenteva)
  SELECT code, code
  FROM edenteva
  WHERE time = '1340252716' AND code = '571119'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE edenteva = VALUES(edenteva) ;
```

Good ole SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bb19/1

Answer (score 2):

Well, you give the answer in your question: `check the manual` ...

IF statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html

EXISTS statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Hint: you are confusing regular condition expression IF THEN ELSE with the IF statement within a SQL query, which is different.

Answer (score 0):

IF THEN ELSE is for stored programs in mysql land...

so can only be used like this :( so no good news for you or other people expecting more...

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION SimpleCompare(n INT, m INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

  BEGIN
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);

    IF n > m THEN SET s = '>';
    ELSEIF n = m THEN SET s = '=';
    ELSE SET s = '<';
    END IF;

    SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ', m);

    RETURN s;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
```